# Triangular law of vector addition

Tags: vectors, geometry

We know the triangular law of vector addition but I want to know if there is a proof to prove that the third side vector will be the sum of the first and second side vectors in the triangle? How do we know that the triangular law of vector addition is always correct?

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: It’s a definition. You can’t prove definitions. It s defined this way because physical displacements are observed to work this way.

Comment: I think your question is related to linearity. First: Vectors are elements of vector spaces, e.g. the space of all possible forces that could be exerted on a point mass in 3D space. A vector space has linearity built in, so to say. So IF something is a vector, and you want to add some other vector (which is element of the same vector space) to it : then the triangle rule will ALWAYS apply. The triangle rule is just a visualisation of the addition of vectors (componentwise!).